# Kotlin Coroutines run synchronously in spite of launch method call

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a list of employees and I want to hit the API for each of them. In synchronous mode it takes a lot of time and I want to improve the performance with the coroutines. This is what I've done so far:

```
fun perform() = runBlocking {
    employeesSource.getEmployees()
            .map { launch { populateWithLeaveBalanceReports(it) } }
            .joinAll()
}

suspend fun populateWithLeaveBalanceReports(employee: EmployeeModel) {
        println("Start ${COUTNER}")
        val receivedReports = reportsSource.getReports(employee.employeeId) // call to a very slow API
        receivedReports { employee.addLeaveBalanceReport(it) }
        println("Finish ${COUTNER++}")
    }
```

When I try to run this, the code is being run synchronously and in the console I see the following output:

```
Start 0
Finish 0
Start 1
Finish 1
Start 2
Finish 2
```

which means that the calls are being done sequentially. If I replace this whole code in the `populateWithLeaveBalanceReports` function with `delay(1000)`, it will work asynchronously:

```
Start 0
Start 0
Start 0
Finish 0
Finish 1
Finish 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutines don't magically turn your blocking network API into non-blocking. Use `launch(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` to run blocking tasks in an elastic thread pool. Just note that this doesn't do much more than the plain-old `executorService.submit(blockingTask)`. It's a bit more convenient because it uses a pre-constructed global thread pool.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! When I use this approach, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication` is equal null inside the `populateWithLeaveBalanceReports ` method. I assume it's because SecurityContext is not shared between threads? I'm having troubles calling the API as my token is stored inside the authentication object

Comment: Yes, it's a thread-local holder. It wasn't obvious from your question that you're running this inside a managed Spring app. I'm not sure what's the policy in that context on launching arbitrary threads. But I think you can work around the missing token by retrieving it into a local variable before you enter the `launch` block.

Answer (score 0):

These lines might be using a blocking code - the code that relies on blocking threads to wait for task completion.

`val receivedReports = reportsSource.getReports(employee.employeeId)
receivedReports { employee.addLeaveBalanceReport(it) }`

It is likely that you are using non asynchronous http client or jdbc driver under the hood of `reportsSource.getReports` call .

If so, you should either

1. rewrite the code of `reportsSource.getReports` so it would not rely on any blocking code. This is the new / non-blocking / challenging way
2. use a threadPool executor to distribute executions manually instead of using coroutines. This is the old / simple way.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm using webflux's `WebClient` in order to hit the API. But I'm using it in non-reactive way with the `block()` method. Which http client can be used instead? Fuel library maybe??

Comment: Why don't you continue using WebClient but start using it in a non-blocking way? Spring has built-in support for Kotlin coroutines.